# Matlab removing row based on random value

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

I have matrix

```
A = [1 2;2 2;3 3;4 3;5 3;6 3;7 2;8 3;9 2;10 2;11 3;12 3;13 2;14 2;15 3]
```

I need to randomly remove 10 row from `A`.
I am using with this code:

```
for i = 1:10
    x = randi([2  3],1);
    A(any(A==x,2),:)=[];
end
```

so `A` remaining five rows only. 
thank you so much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to randomly remove 10 rows out of 15, you baiscally need to [`randsample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) the rows to remove:

```
num_to_remove = 10;
idx = randsameple( size(A,1), num_to_remove );
A(idx,:) = [];  % remove the sampled rows
```

You only need to make sure `size(A,1) >= num_to_remove`.

---

PS,
It is best not to use `i` [as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: I think that `randsample` may be a bit overkill here. `randsample` is from the Statistics and Machine Learning toolbox and has several options that aren't being used here. A call to [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) would accomplish the same thing and comes with vanilla MATLAB.